# Is there a way to run a Python script that is triggered by a message received through Microsoft Teams?

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

I wanted to create a script that can read a microsoft teams message and run a python application based on that message. I tried doing some research but haven't been able to find anything other than Microsoft Bot, but it doesn't seem to do what I need.

Comment: AWS lambda is a trigger based service.You can use it to run python scripts based on some trigger. You just need to find a way to send your messages to the AWS cloud as soon as you receive them(once you have the messages, you can put it to AWS stream to avoid delay).                                                                                                        https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/  This article may be of some help ..https://medium.com/@sebastian.phelps/aws-cloudwatch-alarms-on-microsoft-teams-9b5239e23b64

Comment: Thanks Akshit, definitely gives some insight into the research I am doing. I was hoping to run the python script when a message has been received rather than an outside event.

Comment: I don't know a lot about microsoft teams but if you are open to choosing alternatives, then you can have a look at Amazon Chime and see how well it interacts with AWS cloud.

Comment: Maybe you'll need a Bot: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations